# SWIG return PyObject as python object?

Tags: python, numpy, swig

Suppose I have a SWIG-wrapped class taking care of a pointer to some data, as shown in the following code. I would like to construct a numpy `ndarray` object from the data and return it to the user. I want it to use the data as it's buffer but not take the ownership. If I'm right, I shall use the numpy C++ api `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`. However, my question is how do I return this to python? If I write the following `get` function, will SWIG automatically return it as a python object? If not, what shall I do?

```
class Test {
 public:
  Test () { ptr_ = new uint8_t[200]; }
  ~Test() { delete [] ptr_; }

  PyObject* get() {
    npy_intp dims[1] = {25};
    return PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, ptr_);
  }

 private:
  uint8_t* ptr_;
};
```

By the way, I'm also struggling in finding the header files and library files for the above api. If you know please also tell me. Thanks.

UPDATE:

I tried SWIG wrap this class. Everything else works good, except when I call the `get` function in python (like the following), I got segmentation fault. Any help is appreciated.

```
x = Test()
y = x.get()
```

UPDATE 2:

It seems that `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` is a deprecated function. So is this still supported or is there any other more recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution using typemap in swig:

```
%typemap(out) double* {
  npy_intp dims[1] = {25};
  $result = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, PyArray_DOUBLE, $1);
}

class Test {
 public:
  Test () { ptr_ = new uint8_t[200]; }
  ~Test() { delete [] ptr_; }

  double* get() {
    return (double*) ptr_;
  }

 private:
  uint8_t* ptr_;
};
```

Comment: I get an compilation error if I try to do with a float*. Any suggestion?