# Create Python buffer object from C++ pointer using SWIG?

Tags: python, numpy, swig

I would like to create a Python buffer object (either writable or not) from a C++ pointer, such that it can be passed to the `numpy.frombuffer` function. Can someone let me know how to do it?

Here is my example SWIG-wrapped C++ function which returns a pointer:

```
uint8_t* some_function() {return new uint8_t[200];}
```

After SWIG wrap it, I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493915/creating-swig-wrapper-for-c-pointers-to-python) to create a buffer object in python:

```
x = some_function()
b = buffer_frompointer(x)
z = numpy.frombuffer(b, dtype=numpy.uint8)
```

The last statement returns an error saying the `__buffer__` attribute is not found. I guess this is because the variable `b` here is not really a buffer object in the python sense. So what shall I do?

ps. I don't want an additional copy of the memory when creating the numpy array.

ps. Let's not worry about the memory leak problem for now.

UPDATE:

I'm still interested in a solution to this question, but in case no one answers it, I'll go with a workaround in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425484/swig-return-pyobject-as-python-object) I asked, although that solution is not preferred because of the use of deprecated interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes, numpy
bptr = int(b.cast())
barray = ctypes.c_byte*200
barray = barray.from_address(bptr)
z = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(barray)
```

Comment: Please don't post answers that contain only code. Go ahead and explain your solution how you solved OP's issue.